# ASP.NET Core: Web API not served over IIS Express - why?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-express

I don't seem to be able to debug my ASP.NET Core Web API using IIS Express.

I'm always getting a `404 File not found` response.

When I use Kestrel for debugging, everything works fine.

Why isn't IIS Express working?

This is my `launchSettings.json` file:

```
{
    "iisSettings":
    {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress":
        {
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52772/Users",
            "sslPort": 0
        }
    },
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "profiles":
    {
        "IIS Express":
        {
            "commandName": "IISExpress",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "environmentVariables":
            {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            }
        },
        "WebAPI":
        {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "launchBrowser": true,
            "environmentVariables":
            {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000"
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

Here's a screenshot depicting both situations: Kestrel on the left and IIS Express on the right:

[image]

Please note the HTTP status codes returned.

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args) =>
  Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<WebConfiguration>())
    .Build()
    .Run();
```

```cs
public class WebConfiguration
{
  private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;



  public WebConfiguration(IConfiguration configuration) => _configuration = configuration;



  // This method gets called by the runtime once. Use this method to add services to the container for dependency injection.
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    services
      .AddSingleton(_configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Get<Options>())
      .AddScoped(typeof(IUserAccess), typeof(UserAccess))
      .AddScoped(typeof(ITaskItemAccess), typeof(TaskItemAccess))
      .AddScoped(typeof(IGenderAccess), typeof(GenderAccess))

      .AddSwaggerGen()

      .AddControllers()
      ;
  }

  // This method gets called by the runtime once. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, Options options)
  {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app
      .UseHttpsRedirection()
      .UseRouting()
      .UseAuthorization()
      .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers())
      .UseSwagger()
      ;

    if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseSwaggerUI();
  }
}
```

```cs
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
  [Route("[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class UsersController : ControllerBase
  {
    private readonly IUserAccess _repository;

    public UsersController(IUserAccess repository) => _repository = repository;

    [HttpGet]
    public ICollection<User> Get() => _repository.Get();

...
```

Comment: does it has any User controller or have you set the default route. Just try to remove the users  from the link  http://localhost:52772  and try

Comment: To answer your question: yes, it does. I realized that my question was unclear. I now added a screenshot depicting that the endpoints exist and work as expected under Kestrel but not under IIS Express.

Comment: could you also provide the code in configure method of startup.cs and usercontroller.cs class?

Comment: Can you turn on the developerexceptionpage and show us the actual exception.

Comment: I now added the missing code parts. @DurgaPrasad: Developer Exception Page is already enabled. There is no exception. An HTTP `404` means there is no code to call. ASP.NET isn't even triggered. So this is not an issue with my code but there's something wrong with IIS Express.

Comment: asp.net core 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind just any urls to applicationUrl property, only 3 typs of url can be bound

```
 1. {scheme}://{loopbackAddress}:{port} (e.g. http://localhost:3000)
 2. {scheme}://{IPAddress}:{port} (e.g. http://192.168.2.130:3000)
 3. {scheme}://*:{port} (e.g. http://*:3000)
```

though port is optional, if not mentioned default 80 for http and 443 for https is bound

If your requirement is to launch a controller by default,
You can leave applicationUrl to base url and add launchUrl property with controller name in it

[image]

Comment: What's this supposed to change? That's not an answer to my question.

Comment: Updated, check it now. I thought you would understand.

Comment: Nice thought. But as I wrote before: No difference.

Comment: it's still  not working for you? It should work mate. Can we do Live share?

Comment: Sure. That would be great. How can I reach you for details?

Comment: Ok, please share the Live share link, we can connect via live share.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't grant Live Share access to folks outside my organization.

Comment: I just created a temporary VM to be able to fiddle around with and enabled Live Share in that VM. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/CucumberCheery/9jybdgu4/1/ (it's in the HTML section)

Comment: I opened it in my visual studio and removed the trailing slash from 'applicationUrl', can you try now.

Comment: I can't find a chatting option in Live Share. There's supposed to be one, but I cannot find it. Can you trigger a chat session in Live Share?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: share your localhost

Comment: Have you seen my Skype invitation? Communication should improve when we're using I chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219997/discussion-between-rajdeep-debnath-and-axd).